# if conditionals in pandoc templates depending on value of a variable

Tags: if-statement, pandoc

In pandoc, you can see if you have a variable or not (`$if(something)$ put $something$ $endif$`), but I want to act depending on its value. Something like:

```
$if(lang)=='en'$ Hello $else$ Aloha $endif$
```

Is it possible? In [Pandoc Manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) I don't see nothing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That would have been inside Pandoc Manual if there was such a feature and according to this [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/jvJvN2jlK50) it is not possible with [pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc).

What it is possible, is to define some more general variables that will contain things you want to change.

For example if you want to use the English language, set a variable `lang.en` and check it with `$if(lang.en)$`. If you want another language then unset `lang.en` and set `lang.fr` and use it like this:

```
$if(lang.en)$
Hello
$else$
Aloha
$endif$

$if(lang.fr)$
Bonjour
$else$
Aloha
$endif$
```

Comment: Perhaps we could add a request issue